# How to append multiple python dictionaries to a list using a for loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
def get_property_details(url):

    page = r.get(URL)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'list-card-heading uk-grid')
    
    try:
        prop_info = {}
        property_list = []
        count = 0
        for d in div:
            
            details = d.find_all('li')
            prop_info['Price'] = d.find('b', class_ = 'list-price').get_text().strip().replace('$','').replace('/mo','').replace('\xa0','')
            prop_info['Type'] = d.find('span', class_ = 'rent_type').get_text().strip()
            
            for index, detail in enumerate(details):
                if index == 0:
                    prop_info['Bed'] = detail.text.strip().replace(' bds','')   
                elif index == 1:
                    prop_info['Bath'] = detail.text.strip().replace(' ba','')          
                elif index == 2:
                    prop_info['SQFT'] = detail.text.strip().replace(' sqft','')             
                else:
                    break
            # This prints out the correct property details
            print(prop_info)
            # This is not working, add the same property repeatedly 
            property_list.append(prop_info)
                        
    except Exception as e:
        print()
        
    # list of dictionary  
    return property_list
```

URL = 'https://www.forrentbyowner.com/?showpage=/classifieds/&f=Oklahoma'
property_info = get_property_details(URL)
print(property_info)

Comment: Kindly explain what your code does, errors you are facing and what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: It loops through the web page and grabs listing price, rent type, how many beds, how many baths, and the sqft. It is creating a list of dictionary items but creating the same object for each iteration. Imported deepcopy and appended that to list. That seemed to work for one page but every page afterwards copied the what was returned from the first list.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you are adding the same object all the time, remember that Python uses a "call by object reference" system to pass arguments to functions, which means that when you pass arguments like strings, numbers, or tuples it can be considered as "call by value" arguments, but mutable objects can be considered as "call by reference" arguments, so you are appending the same object reference all the time, to avoid that, you just need to move `prop_info = {}` inside the for loop to create a new instance of the `prop_info` dictionary:

```py
    ...
    try:
        property_list = []
        count = 0
        for d in div:
            prop_info = {}    
            details = d.find_all('li')
            prop_info['Price'] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will give that a go. I ended up using deepcopy() and was able to get the first page to work but every page afterwards I had the same issue. It copied the list from the first page to the remaining pages.

Answer (score 0):

here is a bit modified code, you don't need that extra dictionary and for loop

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_property_details(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find_all('div', class_='list-card-heading uk-grid')
    # prop_info = {}
    property_list = []
    try:
        # count = 0
        for d in div:
            details = d.find_all('li')
            property_list.append({'price': d.find('b', class_='list-price').get_text().strip().replace('$', '').replace('/mo', '').replace('\xa0', ''),
                                  'Type': d.find('span', class_='rent_type').get_text().strip(),
                                  'Bed': details[0].text.strip().replace(' bds', '').replace(' bd', ''),
                                  'Bath': details[1].text.strip().replace(' ba', ''),
                                  'SQFT': details[2].text.strip().replace(' sqft', '')})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    # list of dictionary
    return property_list


URL = 'https://www.forrentbyowner.com/?showpage=/classifieds/&f=Oklahoma'
property_info = get_property_details(URL)
print(property_info)
```

Hope this will help, a small suggestion modify your question so that it can be easily understood